# Loading a PKCS-12 keystore in AEM 6.0

Tags: aem, keystore, saml

I am trying to move my SAML integration code from a CQ 5.6.1 environment to AEM 6.0.

While my login works correctly, I'm stuck at the logout implementation. The same snippet of code runs on 5.6.1, but throws an I.O Exception in AEM 6.0

Here's the code in question

```
     Node contentNode = resourceResolver.getResource("path_to_cert")
            .adaptTo(Node.class);

    Binary content = contentNode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary();
    log.info("Binary data from certificate -->"+content);

    InputStream stream = content.getStream();

    KeyStore keyStoreFile = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStoreFile.load(stream, "Newuser@123".toCharArray());
```

And here is the error I see :-

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not decrypt data.
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gx.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at
```

This snippet works perfectly fine on CQ 5.6.1, and the certificates generated in both 5.6.1 and AEM 6.0 are identical, created on my Java 7 machine.

Are there any certificate/keystore related changes unique to AEM 6.0 that is causing this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have had a similar issue and solved it by passing a provider-String:

`Keystore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE")`

Comment: @ konstantin Do you know why such issues occur, generally? I was under the impression PKCS12 is always implemented in Java, therefore, there would be no need of passing a provider explicitly.

Comment: Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the KeyStore type PKCS12. getInstance("PKCS12"); traverses the list of registered security Providers, starting with the most preferred Provider. A new KeyStore object from the first Provider that supports PKCS12 is returned. Which providers are registered? You can get a list of registered providers with Security.getProviders()